# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array during decryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

i use the below code during login i get the following error

Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Line 24:  byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(txtpas.Text);

```
 protected void txtlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(txtpas.Text);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                txtpas.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());

                if (u.Login(txtuser.Text, txtpas.Text) == true)
                {
                    UtilityClass.CreateCookie("login", new string[] { "username", "usertypeid" }, new string[] { txtuser.Text, u.UserTypeID.ToString().Trim() }, !chkrem.Checked, Response);
                    Response.Redirect("SiteAdmin/index.aspx");
                }
                else
                {

                    Label1.Text = "“Invalid Username or Password”";

                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: What do you _expect_ `Convert.FromBase64String(txtpas.Text)` to do? Why do you think a password is encoded in base64? Don't you mean `ToBase64String`, or perhaps `byte[] cipherBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordString)`?

Comment: It is clear that `txtpas.Text` doesn't contain a valid base64 encoded string.

Comment: should i put the result from encryption code to txtpas.Text?

Comment: @HisHis That would be a good idea. Otherwise, we can't determine what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what a Base64 string is doing.  It is breaking 8-bit bytes on 6-bit boundaries and assigning a text character corresponding to the value of those bits.  If you have 1 byte, you will have 2 Base64 characters (plus the extra characters always tacked on the end of Base64 strings).  One of those Base64 characters can be anything in the 64-member "alphabet" where the other will be one of 4 characters depending on the settings of those last 2 bits.

If you have 2 bytes to encode, these 16 bits become 3 Base64 characters, the last character of which can only be from the lower 16 (4 bits) of the Base64 alphabet.

And so on.  3 bytes is 24 bits and needs 4 Base64 characters to represent them.  But under what circumstances will we ever need exactly 5 Base64 characters?  Never.  3 bytes fits into 4 characters and 4 bytes needs 6 characters.  Any Base64 string exactly 5 characters long is not a good representation of any integral number of bytes.  And these invalid lengths repeat every so often throughout the number range.

Now that's not to say a simple compression algorithm couldn't truncate trailing 0 bits and manufacture a 5 character Base64 string, but it is not normal and will throw exceptions if you try to convert it to bytes from such lengths.